# Connect to resources of 2 different AWS accounts via roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Consider 2 AWS accounts A ( Other team ) and B ( Mine )
For my use case, I have to poll to queues in A's AWS account for payload and perform database operations in B.
To do this, I have a role created in B having access to my databases + A's account ID as trusted relationship.
Likewise A has created a role for granting access to queue in A + added B as trusted relationship.

Code for doing all the polling + database action will reside on EC2 in my account ( B ).
Now how do I consume payloads and perform operations from a role's perspective. Is my understanding correct?

1. Assume role A
2. Poll to provisioning queue, get the JSON payload from SQS
3. Assume role B
4. Perform database operations in Oracle RDS
5. Assume role A
6. Return back the response to response SQS
7. Start polling again on provisioning queue SQS

FYI : I am performing the above operations using Python + Boto3

Comment: Could you please clarify which services you are using in which account? For example, is Step 2 accessing an SQS queue? What type of database is Step 4 using? What do you mean by "Return back the response" in Step 6? Return to where? Feel free to edit your Question to clarify these points.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Added the clarifications.

Comment: When you "Perform database operations in Oracle RDS", what type of credentials are you using? This would typically be a database login rather than IAM credentials.

Comment: I'm using cx_Oracle to connect to database using JDBC connections.

Comment: In that case, what is Role B being used for? How is Role B relevant to the database operations?

Comment: Because database is also an RDS in an AWS account right, will role B not necessary to interact with this database? And just FYI, I also need to use SES from role B along with database stuff.

Comment: Amazon RDS for Oracle logins do not use IAM credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which programming language or SDK you are using, but essentially you can create two client/service objects, one leveraging credentials from role A and the other from role B. Then simply make API calls using the appropriate client/service object.

Using boto3, for example:

```
sqs_accounta = boto3.client(
    'sqs',
    region_name='us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id=xxx,
    aws_secret_access_key=yyy,
    aws_session_token=zzz
)

rds_accountb = boto3.client(
    'rds',
    region_name='us-west-2',
    aws_access_key_id=aaa,
    aws_secret_access_key=bbb,
    aws_session_token=ccc
)
```

Comment: I am using Python + Boto3. Currently, I create clients for whichever resource I want to make use of and call the functions, but while creating clients I don't provide any role as such, just the service name and the region.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assuming roles, you can grant [Cross-Account access to the queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-sqs-policies.html#grant-cross-account-permissions-to-role-and-user-name) in Account A to the user/role in Account B.

In your case, grant it to EC2 instance role and then you'll be able to do all the required operations from within the instance without any "Assume role" tricks.

Comment: Hey I am using cross-account roles only using the trusted relationship, but my understanding was I still need to assume the role to poll queue, is that not the case?

Comment: No. With cross-account access, your role in Account B would have the permissions to read queue from Account A.

Answer (score 0):

Pretend for a moment that everything was happening in your own account (Account-B).

You would give a set of credentials to your code (either an IAM User or, if the code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, you would assign an IAM Role to the instance) that it can use to access the necessary resources in Account B. So, no problem there.

The only additional requirement is that you wish to access Amazon SQS in Account-A. It so happens that you can **add permissions directly to an Amazon SQS queue** that grants cross-account access.

See: [Basic Examples of IAM Policies for Amazon SQS - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-iam-policies.html)

So, **you do not actually need to assume *any* roles**. Just use the normal credentials that are assigned to your code, and add permissions to the SQS queue to allow that particular IAM User or IAM Role to use the queue.